# Single word for the act of being susceptible?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I want a single word verb to express the action of actively having been the victim of susceptibilities.

For example, as a standard use of the word susceptible:

> Bob was a recovering alcoholic, and was susceptible to relapsing.

I want to word that describes that he actually did fall victim to the thing he was susceptible to.

> Last night Bob [supceeded] to his alcoholism and went on a bender.

Comment: The title is a paradox, either it's the act or the state.

Comment: *He fell victim to his alcoholism*

Comment: You have it right there in your post: _relapse_.

Comment: @TonyK That wouldn't work in other contexts. 'The child relapsed to a a respiratory illness'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He succumbed to his alcoholism and went on a bender.

[Succumb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succumb):

> to yield to superior strength or force or overpowering appeal or desire. "succumb to temptation"

Comment: That's the first word that popped into my head. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

A verb that can be used here is ***surrender***.

> Last night Bob ***surrenderred*** to his alcoholism and went on a
>   bender.

ODO:

> **[surrender](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/surrender)**
>   *VERB*
>   **1.2** (*surrender to*) Give in to (a powerful emotion or influence):
>   ‘the president has surrendered to panic and is making things worse’
>
> ‘I say that we cannot surrender to those temptations.’